# Open the best Reddit posts with Nim

Tags: console, http, reddit, nim

I wanted to try out the Nim language so I wrote a simple program to retrieve the top \$n\$ messages on a given subreddit in a given time frame and open them in the default browser.

I would really appreciate your feedback on how to do things more idiomatically.

```
import std/[strformat, rdstdin, parseutils]
import std/[httpclient, json, browsers]

let
    headers: HttpHeaders = newHttpHeaders({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})

proc get_best_posts_url(subreddit: string, t: string = "week", count: int = 1): seq[string] =
    var url = fmt"https://www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/top.json?t={t}&limit={count}"
    var client = newHttpClient(headers=headers)
    var response = client.get(url)
    var json = parseJson(response.body)
    var posts = json["data"]["children"].getElems()
    for post in posts:
        result.add(post["data"]["url"].getStr())

proc open_best_posts(subreddit: string, t: string = "week", count: int = 1) =
    for url in get_best_posts_url(subreddit, t, count):
        openDefaultBrowser url

when isMainModule:
    var subreddit = readLineFromStdin("Enter subreddit: ")
    var t = readLineFromStdin("Enter time period (day, week, month, year, all): ")
    var count: int
    discard readLineFromStdin("Enter number of posts: ").parseInt(count)
    open_best_posts(subreddit, t, count)
```

Answer (score 1):

- The code is straightforward to read and understand.
- Nim idiomatically uses two spaces for indentation, not four (see e.g. the [standard library style guide](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nep1.html#introduction-spacing-and-whitespace-conventions), or all code examples in the [official tutorial](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html)).
- The style guide advises to use `camelCase` for identifiers like function names, not `snake_case` (given Nim's [style insensitivity](https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/manual.html#lexical-analysis-identifier-equality) this is more open to personal preference, however this feature is [considered to be removed from the language](https://github.com/nim-lang/RFCs/issues/456)).
- Nim has two keywords for declaring variables: `var` and `let`. The difference is that variables declared with `var` can be changed after being declared (and they do not need to be initialized) and variables declared with `let` cannot (they are *immutable*). It is always a good idea to use immutable variables where possible, because this eliminates the mental load of tracking where a variable is changed during a program (it can also help the compiler optimize the program, but I think this is not important in this case). This is also covered in the [standard library style guide](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nep1.html#introduction-coding-conventions).

  All variable declarations in your program can be changed to `let`, except `count` in the `when isMainModule:` block (it is declared uninitialized and then needs to be changed by `parseInt`).
- The program allows the user to any string for the time period. <s>I could not test what happens when the user enters nonsense, because I did not have SSL set up, but probably the program should do some input validation to avoid sending incorrect parameters to the Reddit API.</s>

  After compiling with `-d:ssl` it seems to me that the Reddit API accepts any string for the time period and number of posts and uses default values, so the input validation might not be needed.